# href da base de dados mysql com jquery

Tags: jquery

tenho uma questão pra resolver e conto com a ajuda de vocês esse código não exibe o conteúdo da variável .

```
<li style="width:290px; border:#f00 0px solid;"><a href="#" class="link"   data-text="<?php echo  $n1['nick'];?>"  >Pronto</a></li>

$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".link").click(function(){
         var nomes = $(this).text("data-text");
         alert(nomes);       
         $('a[href=#]').attr('href', nome ) 


         });


})
```

Answer (score 0):

Pelo teor do código, você quer pegar o valor do atributo `data-text` e jogar para o `href` do link. Porém há 3 problemas:

Você pega o atributo `data` da seguinte forma:

```
var nomes = $(this).data("text");
```

Este seletor é inválido:

```
$('a[href=#]')
```

Deve-se, neste caso, colocar o símbolo `#` entre aspas:

```
$('a[href="#"]')
```

E a variável `nome` aqui não existe (talvez apenas um erro de digitação):

```
$('a[href=#]').attr('href', nome )
```

O código corrigido fica assim:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".link").click(function(){
      var nomes = $(this).data("text");
      alert(nomes);       
      $('a[href="#"]').attr('href', nomes ) ;
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li style="width:290px; border:#f00 0px solid;">
   <a href="#" class="link" data-text="<?php echo  $n1['nick'];?>">Pronto</a>
</li>
```